# How to decrypt data stored in sessionStorage

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I have a Spring Boot backend and Angular 5 as frontend app. I lost a lot of time in googling but without any answer.
I have to store some sensitive data in sessionStorage, for that I have to encrypt it. The problem is how to recover this data and decrypt it to do some operations.

This is scenario:

1. the client is logged in
2. store his id in sessionStorage(encrypted). I am using sessionStorage to keep data available to other components even if the page is refreshed
3. recover this encrypted id in other components, decrypt it and do some operations with the database

Comment: What exactly is the *problem* with your current implementation? Also what does the backend have to do with this?

Comment: Are you able to encrypt the data though? If you have already figured that out, you need to let us know what you are already doing for the community to help.

Comment: Decrypt by doing the opposite of what you did to encrypt the data.